# What to do with out-of-date Flickr questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

We have a number of questions about Flickr where the answer was essentially "get a Pro account" - I trivially found [Can I download all of my flickr photos after the expiration of “Pro” subscription?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17642/can-i-download-all-of-my-flickr-photos-after-the-expiration-of-pro-subscriptio) and https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/how-could-i-prevent-involuntary-resize-of-pictures-by-flickr, but I'm guessing there are more out there. The answers were perfectly correct when given, but with Flickr having pushed almost all the pro functionality into their free accounts, the answers aren't really helpful any more. What's the best thing to do with this sort of question?

One possibilities I see would include posting a new answer saying "not relevant any more" and hoping it gets upvoted, but is there anything better we can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's close 'em. Maybe and delete them?

Comment: Just closing them when we know the answers are wrong would seem wrong to me. Deleting them seems reasonable though - there's nothing of value in those questions to anyone any more.

Comment: Unless there are any objections, I'll flag these two and any other similar Flickr questions in the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: And done. I've flagged the two questions mentioned in the original post and [Flickr removing exif from “shared” images](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/flickr-removing-exif-from-shared-images), and proposed an edit to the accepted answer on [Does Flickr recompress JPEGs after upload?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12423/does-flickr-recompress-jpegs-after-upload).